# How to edit existing mysql data "unique" if it duplicates or more

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, unique

I have a table like this:

[image]

I use alias in my links as http://www.yoursite.com/ALIAS

So they must be unique.

But i have nearly 1 million rows that's why when i use code at below, it takes time so much, and site down.

By the way, what is your advice for me?

Thanks a lot.

```
$sql2="SELECT id,adi,alias from firma where id>1400 and id<100000 and onay=0 ";
    $gor=mysqli_query($i_link,$sql2);
    while($sonuc=mysqli_fetch_row($gor))
    {
        $alias=$sonuc['2'];
        $ee="SELECT id from firma where alias='".$alias."' ";
        $says=mysqli_query($i_link,$ee);
        $say=mysqli_num_rows($says);
        if($say>1) 
            {
                $r=rand(0,999);
                $aliasy=$alias."-".$r;
        mysqli_query($i_link,"UPDATE firma SET alias='".$aliasy."' WHERE id='".$sonuc['0']."' ");

            }
        }
```

Comment: select distinct

Comment: this works for to select distinct (different) values, i must edit all rows

Comment: SELECT COUNT(id) from firma where alias='".$alias."'

Comment: i'll try to do all by SQL, as i see it would be done, got hard work

Comment: UPDATE firma SET alias='"{{here need to find how to get alinas and add rand}}"' WHERE id>1400 and id<100000 and onay=0

Answer (score 1):

This is what your code seems to be doing:

1. Get all the rows from `table`, with an id `range`
2. For each row, get the alias
3. Get row count for each alias, check if it is more than 1
4. If row count is more than 1, update rows with alias prefixed by random number

Step 1 to 3 are a bit redundant as you are re-fetching the same data, I would recommend fetching only those aliases which appear more than once and update them. Below is an example query to get all such aliases:

```
SELECT alias, GROUP_CONCAT(id)
FROM test
WHERE id >= 1 AND id <= 335003
GROUP BY alias
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

This query will give you the aliases that appear more than once, you can then iterate through these, get the ids and update the corresponding records. This will save you one iteration and will make the app faster.

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5eee4/4/0)**.